# What is wrong with my hadoop-yarn configuration

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I have one problem with my yarn .It is a dev test environment.make up with 3 ubuntu virtual machine .

Here is an analog:

1,after run start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh.Type jps in the console,it shows:

```
hadoop@zonlolo101:~$ jps
9895 Jps
9649 ResourceManager
9323 NameNode
9520 SecondaryNameNode
```

2,run ' hadoop jar /opt/cloud/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /input /output/out' command:

```
14/04/16 18:22:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1397643671624_0002
14/04/16 18:23:23 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cloud001/192.168.1.101:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
14/04/16 18:23:24 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: cloud001/192.168.1.101:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

3 the 8032 port is closed,then check using jps:

```
hadoop@zonlolo101:~$ jps
9323 NameNode
10098 Jps
9520 SecondaryNameNode
```

no resourcemanager runing ,it is closed .

I want to know what is wrong with it .I have check the config. yarn.site.xml is right.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for ur reply.There were hardware resource problems.I have run 4 kvm machines,after 2 machines shutdown.The error has gone

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Datanode is not running. Please refer this link for Setting up the Yarn cluster - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html

Comment: Thanks for ur reply .It due to hardware resource employing.

Answer (score 0):

you can do through shell script please download bellow link.
start run shell script it will fince all nodes one time.
You don't need to run to commands you can use start-all.sh only.
https://github.com/tonyreddy/Cloudera-Hadoop-2.0.0-MultiNode-shell-script

You can use apache hadoop shell script bellow link
https://github.com/tonyreddy/Apache-MultiNode-Insatallation-Shellscript